# PHP ternary operator not working

Tags: php, ternary

The code below takes an array value, if it's key exist it should echo out it's value, the ternary if/else part works but the value is not showing up, can anyone figure out why it won't?

```
$signup_errors['captcha'] = 'error-class';

echo(array_key_exists('captcha', $signup_errors)) ? $signup_errors['catcha'] : 'false';
```

Also where I have it echo out false, I do not need an output if a key does not exist, should I just delete the word false or is there something else to make the code only show 1 value?

Comment: If you only want to output when there are errors, why not just use an if statement?

Comment: PHP ternary operator is working.  You're just not using it correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you've got a parenthesis in the wrong place:

```
echo(array_key_exists('captcha', $signup_errors) ? $signup_errors['captcha'] : 'false');
```

Also, check your spelling of `'captcha'`.

Comment: The parentheses are OK. Actually they're pretty much useless in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo. This:

```
? $signup_errors['catcha'] :
```

Should be this:

```
? $signup_errors['captcha'] :
```

catcha -> captcha

Comment: He's got two typos. Look closer.

Comment: Chris, that's the only one I could spot. And I tested the code in the CLI actually.

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant:

```
echo(array_key_exists('captcha', $signup_errors) ? $signup_errors['captcha'] : 'false');
```

Or if you want no output when the key doesn't exist, use an 'if' statement, not the ternary operator:

```
if (array_key_exists('captcha', $signup_errors)) { echo $signup_errors['captcha']; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelled 'captcha' as 'catcha'.